# Checking type of parameter

Tags: c#

I would like to check, which type a parameter of a method has, in order to give 
the variable I determine inside the method with the wished type:

```
public static Object getFileContent(String filename, Type returntype)
{
     if (returntype.GetType().Equals(string))
     {
       // do something
     }
}
```

This doesn't work. What could I do, to check if returntype is `string` or `List<string>`?

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off using a generic method here, `public static T getFileContent<T>(String filename)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
returntype == typeof(string)
```

No need to call `GetType` because you already *have* a type. (`GetType` would not return a useful answer anyway, it would return typeof(Type)).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`typeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) operator instead

```
 if (returntype.Equals(typeof(string)))
 {
   // do something
 }
```

or just

```
 if (returntype == typeof(string))
 {
   // do something
 }
```

Comment: @MarcGravell I was gettin' to that ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(returnType == typeof(String) || return == typeof(List<String>))
    //logic
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you just want to check that that `returntype` is the same type as `string`.  When comparing `Type` instances the best route is to simply use the `==` operator

```
return returntype == typeof(string);
```

If you having to be dealing with COM interfaces though you will want to use the `IsEquivalentTo` method instead of `==`

```
return returntype.IsEquivalentTo(typeof(TheInterface));
```

This is necessary because embedded interop types in COM will show up as different `Type` instances.  The `IsEquivalentTo` method will check to see if they represent the same underlying type.

Answer (score -1):

I rather prefer the `is` operator myself:

```
if (returntype is string)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: The type of returntype is always `Type`. The question is if this `Type` equals `typeof(string)`.

Comment: Again: this syntax doesn’t exist. You are conflating C#’s `as`-cast operator and VB’s `TypeOf … Is …` operator here.

Comment: OK, seriously:  What is wrong with `is`? I suppose you don't use `as` either?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Am I?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @KennethK. Yes. Okay, the syntax exists but the result will always be `false` because the type of `returntype` is `System.Type`, not `System.String`.

Comment: `is` compares an *instance* and a type, your answer is comparing a *type* (note `returntype` is declared as `Type` in the method signature) and a type.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Ah, I missed the `Type` type in the OP. Point taken.

Comment: @KonradRudolph nobody conflating C# and VB. It's OP missed calling GetType on parameter of `Type` type.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Ah, that makes sense. Yes, the VB code would actually have the exact same issue.